# React Native error undefined is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently trying redux action creators on react native, I get this error trying to authenticate user.

```
export function authenticate(email, password) {
return (dispatch) => { dispatch(request());
    fetch(path + '/api/v1/account/authenticate', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }, body: qs.stringify({ email: email, password: password }) })
        .then((r) => { return r.json(); })
        .then((a) => {
            if(a.success === false) { dispatch(failure(a)); }  
            AsyncStorage.setItem('hash', a.hash);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('token', a.token); 
                dispatch(success(a)); })
        .catch((error) => { dispatch(failure(error)); });
}

function success(payload) { return { type: constants.__authenticate_success, payload: payload }; }
function failure(payload) { return { type: constants.__authenticate_failure, payload: payload }; }
function request() { return { type: constants.__authenticate_request }; }
```

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhzR7.png)

The full code is:

```
import qs from 'querystring';
import { constants } from './account.constants';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const path = 'https://test.dev';

export function authenticate(email, password) {
    return (dispatch) => { dispatch(request());
        fetch(path + '/api/v1/account/authenticate', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
            body: qs.stringify({ email, password }) }).then((r) => { return r.json(); })
            .then((a) => {
                if(a.success === false) { dispatch(failure(a)); }  
                AsyncStorage.setItem('hash', a.hash);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('token', a.token); 
                    dispatch(success(a)); })
            .catch((error) => { dispatch(failure(error)); });
    }

    function success(payload) { return { type: constants.__authenticate_success, payload: payload }; }
    function failure(payload) { return { type: constants.__authenticate_failure, payload: payload }; }
    function request() { return { type: constants.__authenticate_request }; }
}

export function connectivity() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        AsyncStorage.multiGet(['hash', 'token']).then((r) => { const token = r[1][1]; const hash = r[0][1]; 
            if(token && hash) {
                fetch(path + '/api/v1/account/connectivity', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
                body: qs.stringify({ token: token, hash: hash }) }).then((r) => { return r.json(); })
                    .then((a) => { console.log(a);
                        if(a.hasOwnProperty('message') && a.message === 'Unauthenticated.') { dispatch(failure({ connected: false, logout: true })); }
                        else if(a.logout === true) { dispatch(failure(a)); }
                        else { dispatch(success(a)); }
                    }).catch((error) => { dispatch(failure({ connected: false, logout: true })); });
            } else { dispatch(failure({ connected: false })); }
        }).catch((error) => { dispatch(failure({ connected: false, logout: true })); })
    }

    function success(payload) { return { type: constants.__connectivity_success, payload: payload }; }
    function failure(payload) { return { type: constants.__connectivity_failure, payload: payload }; }
}

export function clear() { return (dispatch) => { 
    //AsyncStorage.multiRemove(['token', 'hash']);
    dispatch({ type: constants.__clear_state }); } }

export function fetch() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((r) => { const token = r;
            if(token) {
                fetch(path + '/api/v1/account/fetch', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token } }).then((r) => { return r.json(); })
                    .then((a) => {

                    }).catch((error) => { dispatch(failure({ account: false })); })
            } else { dispatch(failure({ account: false })); };
        }).catch((error) => dispatch(failure({ account: false })) );
    }

    function success(payload) { return { type: constants.__fetch_account_success, payload: payload }; }
    function failure(payload) { return { type: constants.__fetch_account_failure, payload: payload }; }
}
```

the action is fired in a react component using this function:

```
onSend(event) { this.setState({ loading: true }); this.props.authenticate(this.state.email, this.state.password); }
```

The error image comes from my android emulator using Android Studio. the first time the code worked well, but after that nothing works anymore.

Comment: Can you provide the full code of this file?

Comment: I provided the action creators file code.

Comment: where it throw the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have  declared a function named `fetch` and you are trying to use the `fetch` function of the Fetch API, which has the same name.